# Is it better for performance to disable unused default core views?

Tags: views, 8, performance

I'm seeing 5 views on my site that I'm not using and want to disable to keep things clean and performant, but I worry it could cause a problem somewhere down the road.

The views are:

- Frontpage (frontpage)
- Recent content (content_recent)
- Taxonomy Term (taxonomy_term)
- Who's New (who_s_new)
- Who's Online (who_s_online)

I have disabled these views and haven't seen any issues. I am not using any of them. Is core expecting these to be enabled? Does disabling these actually improve performance in any way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am not using any of them. Is core expecting these to be enabled?

They are just examples and can be disabled if you don't need them.

The taxonomy term view is a bit different because that is the one that provides list of content when clicking on a term, if you disable that then those pages become practically meaningless as all they do is show the term with its fields.

> Does disabling these actually improve performance in any way?

Most likely not a in a measurable way. There are a handful of routes less due to that that don't need to be regenerated on a cache clear but that's a tiny amount of the total routes and it should have no impact on runtime performance.

Comment: Thanks @Berdir - I am using rabbit_hole to hide term pages anyway.